# Importing required external implicits or merging implicits to get one common import

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, scala-cats

I am creating a library to handle fixed-length using Scala.

For encoding and decoding the `strings` I use type class based system. I have provided my own `Read[A]` and `Write[A]` for handling this actions.

My `Write` type class is using `Show` from `Cats` under the hood. It works, but it requires the user to explicitly import *cats'* implicits, like:

```
import com.github.atais.util.Read._
import cats.implicits._
import com.github.atais.util.Write._
```

the example could be seen on the Github project:
https://github.com/atais/Fixed-Length/blob/702d7d242e5b1f6e1c6b581ad7356f36ca6ed8d9/src/test/scala/com/github/atais/fixedlength/simple/CodecTest.scala

Is there any walk-around? I would like to hide the `cats` import or (if possible) merge all three into a single implicit object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cats` stores typeclass instances inside special traits that you can extend to turn your objects into providers themselves. Instances are grouped by type however, so you can take all instances for `Int`, `AnyVal` or `List`, but not "anything with `Show`".

For example, you can extend [`AnyValInstances`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/e2590c6/core/src/main/scala/cats/instances/anyval.scala), so this will compile (in a worksheet)

```
import cats.Show
import cats.instances.AnyValInstances


trait Write[A]

object Write extends AnyValInstances {
    implicit def writeForCatsShow[A](implicit s: Show[A]): Write[A] = new Write[A] { }
}

import Write._

implicitly[Write[Int]] // Show[Int] is in scope
```

There is a caveat, however. Importing instances from `cats` will cause compilation error due to `Show[Int]` being ambiguous:

```
import Write._
import cats.implicits._

// implicitly[Write[Int]] // this will fail to compile b/c we have Show[Int] twice
```

My preference would be to write some boilerplate code to avoid burdening users with imports at all.

```
object file1 {
  // pretend it's a different file
  import cats.Show
  import cats.implicits._ 

  trait Write[A]

  object Write {

    // implement generic Show <-> Write here
    private def fromShow[A](implicit s: Show[A]): Write[A] = new Write[A] { }

    // manually create instances for types you need
    implicit val intWrite  = fromShow[Int]
    implicit val longWrite = fromShow[Long]
    implicit val doubleWrite = fromShow[Double]
    implicit val stringWrite = fromShow[String]

    // BONUS: define instances for other types that have Show
    // without causing any ambiguities
    implicit def listWrite[A](implicit wa: Write[A]): Write[List[A]] = ???
  }
}

object file2 {
  import file1.Write

  object Methods {
        def testWrite[A](a: A)(implicit write: Write[A]) = 42
    }
}

object file3 {
  import file2.Methods

  // We don't need to import cats.Show OR Write at all
  // because Show instances are resolved in object Write code
  // and Scala automatically looks up Write[A] instances in
  // companion object, so Write[Double] will be picked
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        println(Methods.testWrite(2.11))
    }
}
```

Runnable version of above code is available [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oleg-py/P47S5g9gQ16nydfGle1DKQ)